# How to select the field value if field in all child records are the same

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select

I don't know if I'm wording this question correctly, but here it goes.

This is a web application using java, oracle, hibernate.

I have 2 tables in a one (items) to many (tasks) relationship.

Items

- item_id name
- active_status
- etc

Tasks

- task_id
- item_id
- active_status
- progress_status
- etc

The item's status is made up of the statuses of all of its tasks.  Here's the logic...

- If Item Status is Canceled or On Hold...return Item Active Status
- If there are no tasks, return Completed
- If All Tasks are Active and NOT Superseded, then
- ...return Not Started if all tasks are Not Started
- ...return Completed if all tasks are Completed
- ...return On Hold if all tasks are On Hold
- Otherwise return Started

I want to do this using SQL and map it to a field in my hibernate mapping file.

I've tried many things over the past several days, and can't seem to get it to work.  I tried grouping the records and if 1 record was found, return that status.  I've used decode, case, etc.

Here are a few examples of things I've tried.  In the second example I get a 'not a single group group function' error.

Any thoughts?

```
select decode(i.active_status_id, 'OH', i.active_status_id, 'Ca', i.active_status_id,t.progress_status_id)
        from tasks t 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Items i
                ON i.item_id = t.item_id
        where t.item_id = 10927815 and t.active_status_id = 'Ac' and t.active_status_id != 'Su' 
        group by i.active_status_id, t.progress_status_id;




select case                         
        when (count(*) = 1) then progress_status_id
        else 'St'
        end
        from 
        (select progress_status_id
                from tasks t 
                        where t.item_id = 10927815 and (t.active_status_id = 'Ac' and t.active_status_id != 'Su') group by t.progress_status_id)
```

Comment: Your approach depends on whether your web application will be accessing on an item-by-item basis, or working with lists of items (and the size of these lists)...

Comment: It will be lists of items and on a one by one basis.  There is a main page that lists all of the items (could be up to 1000).  User can click to enter the item details.  Right now the tasks are lazy loaded (batch=select) in the hibernate mapping file.  Currently this status is retrieved using iterators.  The status value is cached using ehcache.  If the value exists in cache, use it, otherwise, iterator over and count the statuses in order to determine item status.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps somthing like this

```
SELECT 
  item_id
, CASE 
    WHEN active_status IN ('Canceled', 'On Hold') THEN active_status
    WHEN t_num = 0 THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN flag_all_active = 1 AND flag_all_not_started = 1 THEN 'Not Started'
    WHEN flag_all_active = 1 AND flag_all_completed = 1 THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN flag_all_active = 1 AND flag_all_on_hold = 1 THEN 'On Hold'
  ELSE 'Started'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      i.item_id
    , i.active_status
    , sum(CASE WHEN t.task_id is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 end ) as t_num
    , MIN( CASE t.active_status WHEN 'Ac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as flag_all_active 
    , MIN( CASE t.progress_status_id WHEN 'Not Starten' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as flag_all_not_started
    , MIN( CASE t.progress_status_id WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as flag_all_completed
    , MIN( CASE t.progress_status_id WHEN 'On Hold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as flag_all_on_hold

  FROM 
    items i
    left outer join tasks t on (t.item_id = i.item_id )
  group by i.item_id
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotations you can use `@Formula("sql query here")` for your derived properties.
See [Hibernate formula docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785) for a (surprisingly brief) explanation.

Alternatively, since you're dealing with relatively large lists of items, it would be better to make the status calculations part of your initial query thus avoiding the database getting hammered by hundreds or thousands of requests. This is what will probably happen if you iterate over each item in the list.

I would recommend joining the status calculation to whatever query you are using to generate your list (presumably in a NamedQuery). This lets your database do all the heavy lifting without being slowed down by the network, which is what it is best at. The [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) give lots of helpful examples of queries you can try.

Comment: I'm not using annotations, but I would use the formula in the mapping file (maybe with the sql schurik posted) such as:


`<property name="itemNumber"
          type="string" formula="
 (  SELECT if.value FROM item_fields if WHERE if.item_id = item_id AND if.field_id = 'itemNumber' ) " />`

Comment: You would have to test it to see if it's generating a query for each item (turn on sql debugging to see what is being generated). If the speed is acceptable then I guess that's ok but bear in mind it won't scale well.